# Does Apache Commons Collections have a ListValuedTreeMap?

Tags: apache-commons, apache-commons-collection

I'm trying to find a pre-built implementation of a MultiValuedTreeMap. In a nutshell, I need a single key to map to multiple values via the use of a List. I then need each key to be stored in a sorted structure, what I imagine should be a tree map - hence the name.

The closest I have found is a ArrayListValuedHashMap: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/index.html

I see no version which uses a TreeMap instead of a HashMap, however.

I am new to the Apache Commons libraries so forgive me if the question is obvious / already solved.

I am also aware I can implement this relatively easily myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct implementation of `ListValuedTreeMap` out of the box. To pass concrete implementation of `List` or `Map` into [`ListValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap.html) is intended class [`AbstractListValuedMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/multimap/AbstractListValuedMap.html)

From javadoc:

> Subclasses specify a Map implementation to use as the internal storage and the List implementation to use as values.

Generic implementation of `ListValuedTreeMap` can be implemented this way:

```
public class ListValuedTreeMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> extends AbstractListValuedMap<K, V> {
    public ListValuedTreeMap() {
        super(new TreeMap<>());
    }

    @Override
    protected List<V> createCollection() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```